# Custom page template not showing on page creation

Tags: theme-development, themes

I'm using underscores as the base for a theme and I can't figure out how to build custom pages templates.

I created a nosidebar.php and put this at its tope

```
<?php /* Template Name: WithoutSidebar */ ?>
```

It won't show on the page creation's dropdown, though. Only custom page I managed to make show there is front-page.php, which is already expected by WP's hierarchy.

I tried many solutions I found on Google (checking the root for style.css, etc) and none worked.

Can someone please shine a light over this?

I'm using WP 4.7.5

Comment: Where did you save this new page template?   It must be in the active theme's directory structure.

Comment: Also use the multiline format as the default themes do, for readability and to ensure that there are no quirks in parsing the header